# Crash a thread in a Win32 application

Tags: c++, winapi, sentry, crashpad

I have an application which implements crash handling and reporting using Google Crashpad and Sentry.

The application implements a watchdog which checks for freezes on critical threads, and aborts the application if it detects such a case.

However, when the "crash" gets reported to Sentry, the thread that "crashed" is, of course, the watchdog thread and not the actual thread which was frozen.

I need to trigger the frozen thread to abort to enable Sentry to correctly group related freezes together for analysis.

On POSIX systems, I can do this trivially:

```
pthread_kill(_threadHandle, SIGABRT);
```

On Windows, however, there doesn't seem to be an equivalent.

`TerminateThread` cleanly kills the thread without triggering an abort, which is not suitable.

I believe that what I want to do is accomplishable with `SuspendThread`, `GetThreadContext` and `ResumeThread`, but how do I do this without significantly corrupting the call stack (which needs to be intact for diagnosis)?

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71529/Exception-Injection-Throwing-an-Exception-in-Other

Comment: Hans - Thank you, unfortunately modifying the instruction pointer causes stack corruption in the final minidump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the trap flag to cause an `EXCEPTION_SINGLE_STEP`.

```
CONTEXT context = { 0 };
context.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_ALL;

if (SuspendThread(hThread) == (DWORD)-1)
    handleError();

if (!GetThreadContext(hThread, &context))
    handleError();

context.EFlags |= 0x100; // set trap flag

if (!SetThreadContext(hThread, &context))
    handleError();

if (ResumeThread(hThread) == (DWORD)-1)
    handleError();
```